# Core Data relationship not set sometimes when downloading using Rest kit

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I have a very odd bug which I find very hard to debug. I have a one to many relationship that is not set for one object fetched. I am using Restkit and Core Data. Here is the json that I download:

```
{ "chapterExerciseFiles" : [  ],
    "chapterExerciseUrls" : [ { "description" : "",
          "id" : 43,
          "name" : "Webbˆvning",
          "title" : "Webbˆvningar",
          "type" : "WEB_EXERCISE_LINK",
          "url" : "http://..."
        } ],
    "fromPage" : 1,
    "id" : 43,
    "index" : 1,
    "isbn" : "9789127434400",
    "pageExercises" : [  ],
    "title" : "Echo 5 Short Stories",
    "toPage" : 5
  } //...
```

The model looks like this:

[image: Model screenshot]

The mapping:

```
+ (RKEntityMapping *)chapterExerciseMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *chapterExerciseMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"ChapterExercise" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

    [chapterExerciseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
     @"index",
     @"title"
     ]];
    [chapterExerciseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id": @"chapterExerciseID",
     @"toPage": @"toPageNumber",
     @"fromPage": @"fromPageNumber"
     }];

    [chapterExerciseMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"chapterExerciseFiles" mapping:[IBResponseMapping exerciseFileMapping]];
    [chapterExerciseMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"chapterExerciseUrls" mapping:[IBResponseMapping exerciseUrlMapping]];
    [chapterExerciseMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"pageExercises" mapping:[IBResponseMapping pageExerciseMapping]];

    return chapterExerciseMapping;
}

+ (RKEntityMapping *)exerciseUrlMapping
{
    RKEntityMapping *exerciseUrlMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"ExerciseUrl" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
    [exerciseUrlMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[
     @"type",
     @"url"
     ]];
    [exerciseUrlMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"description": @"urlDescription",
     @"id" : @"urlID",
     @"name" : @"title",
     @"title" : @"sectionTitle"
     }];

    return exerciseUrlMapping;
}
```

The weird thing is that "some" `chapterExercisesUrls` do get set, but not the first.

Logging Restkit shows that `chapterExerciseUrls` is empty when fetching:

```
<IBChapterExercise: 0x16f2f6b0> (entity: ChapterExercise; id: 0x16f2f6f0 <x-coredata:///ChapterExercise/t529D851C-D8EF-4669-B197-9FF24B5CAE862267> ; data: {
    bookData = nil;
    chapterExerciseFiles =     (
    );
    chapterExerciseID = 43;
    chapterExerciseUrls =     (
    );
    fromPageNumber = 1;
    index = 1;
    pageExercises =     (
    );
    title = "Echo 5 Short Stories";
    toPageNumber = 5;
}),
```

Here is another object that do get the right mapping:

```
<IBChapterExercise: 0x14c73920> (entity: ChapterExercise; id: 0x14c8bae0 <x-coredata:///ChapterExercise/t529D851C-D8EF-4669-B197-9FF24B5CAE862295> ; data: {
    bookData = nil;
    chapterExerciseFiles =     (
    );
    chapterExerciseID = 45;
    chapterExerciseUrls =     (
        "0x14ca2f60 <x-coredata:///ExerciseUrl/t529D851C-D8EF-4669-B197-9FF24B5CAE862296>"
    );
    fromPageNumber = 16;
    index = 3;
    pageExercises =     (
        "0x14cbea40 <x-coredata:///PageExercise/t529D851C-D8EF-4669-B197-9FF24B5CAE862300>",
        "0x14c98af0 <x-coredata:///PageExercise/t529D851C-D8EF-4669-B197-9FF24B5CAE862297>",
        "0x16f30000 <x-coredata:///PageExercise/t529D851C-D8EF-4669-B197-9FF24B5CAE862305>"
    );
    title = "Right up to the Limits";
    toPageNumber = 25;
}),
```

The problem is seen on both OSX and iOS. Any ideas on how to debug this further?

Comment: You should have added unique identifier info to the mappings. Do you know if the disconnected objects are duplicates. If you have 2 items in the response, one is connected and the other isn't?

Comment: Yes, you where right. Setting a unique identifier solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add unique identifier info to the mappings to allow RestKit to find existing items and prevent the creation of duplicates.